# nginx $_REQUEST data empty suddenly then back to normal for no reason

Tags: php, nginx, request

So as the title suggests, this happened the 2nd time on our production server on nginx. It is just in few mins both times. But it is enough to ruin our business as our code depends heavily on $_REQUEST

I made an experiment of changing $_REQUEST to $_GET and $_POST :

```
$_REQUEST['postId'] => $_GET ['postId']
```

and it works (during that downtime).

We used $_REQUEST almost everywhere, we won't use it in the future but...

Note: I have googled but what I found couldn't explain and just made me more confused

Comment: Do you use any proxy or CDN? maybe request was altered by those ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $_REQUEST = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);
```

Bet this gonna solves your problem! Dang php!